# Unsure on new job title for technical/managerial role

Tags: management, title, team-role, position

What are some appropriate titles for a management-level position that involves managerial as well as technical/engineering responsibilities related to network (VoIP), database, and Linux systems engineering?

I'm currently titled as "Lead Network Engineer" however this doesn't fit within the context of the organization as people with the "Lead" portion of their title are considered technical leads that don't manage people, where I do. I've been asked to come up with an appropriate replacement title by human resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network Engineering Manager would be my choice. The other one I have seen used is Primary Network Engineer, which is used here for someone with a leading and partly managerial position who has a Network Engineering Manager over them.

Comment: "Senior Network Engineer" is quite common in your second scenario as well.

Comment: Over here that is used for one step down from Primary, but could be different elsewhere.

Comment: This is the title we all agreed to and most appropriate without being overly wordy. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I would ask Human Resources what they think would be most appropriate or for some suggestions. If they're asking for this change to fit into the corporate culture and existing structure then it's quite likely that they're going to have some idea already of how they would expect your new job title to appear.

Comment: Ironically, HR has asked me to come up with my own title.

Comment: Well that's frustrating. Is  there any sort of precedent (like the lead one you mentioned) you can follow here? I quite like Kilisi's suggestion but you need to be sure it fits into the structure or  they may ask you to change it again!

Comment: @THEDOCTOR pff. In that case why not go nuts. Have you tried getting them to call you 'The Doctor'?

Comment: @NathanCooper - If only I could. I'm still a few promotions away from Time Lord though.